# output redirection in windows on the same line

Tags: windows, windows-7

is it possible to redirect the output of two different commands in a windows batch file on the same line?
For example the output of the first command to go on line 1 of my file and when i'll execute command 2 to append itself on the same line as the previous output.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect output to file or append output to file:

```
echo LINE1, > file.txt
echo LINE2 >> file.txt
```

But there will always be a newline even if the command does not output CRLF (it is the case with echo command, you cannot suppress it)

To have output on the same line you need to use this approach:

```
set content=

ECHO LINE1 > temp.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (temp.txt) do set content=%%i

ECHO LINE2 > temp.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (temp.txt) do set content=%content% %%i

ECHO %content%> result.txt
del temp.txt
```

Comment: In case you are satisfied with this solution, you can consider accepting this answer :-) Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Unless the first program outputs a newline character, you can do the shell redirection-concatenation:

```
prog1 > out.txt
prog2 >> out.txt
```

Comment: isn't there a switch or something in windows command prompt to disable the newline character?

Comment: It's not up to the command shell, but to the application.  The shell just redirects the output, whatever it is, to the specified file.  If there _is_ a newline, you can write a simple program to strip if trom the end of the file and run it before the second command (there might be something out there to do this for you already, but I'm not aware of it)